# Unable to extend partition using unallocate space in linux 18.10 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, disk

I'm using laptop with dual boot windows 7 32-bit along with an ubuntu 18.10 64-bit (laptop supports 64bit) and I can't extend the linux (ext4) partition using the unallocated space.

When I try to resize it says 0 (zero) free space preceeding.

I need help as my ubuntu only has 30GB right now and i need more, the unallocated is huge around 150GB.

[mydiskpartition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5MGF.png)

Comment: You cannot repartition your system (/) partition *while your system is mounted*. I don't know which instructions you are following, but trustworthy directions start with 1) Backup your system, 2) Boot from a Live USB. Find better instructions to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot from a Live USB. Open Gparted. Move efi partition to the end and then resize the '/' partition.